# How to check for the existence of a DB?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, connection-string

I am wondering if there is an elegant way to check for the existence of a DB? In brief, how do test the connection of a db connection string?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set the `Initial Catalog=master` in the connection string and execute:

```
select count(*) from sysdatabases where name = @name
```

with `@name` set to the name of the database.

If you want to check the connection string as a whole (and not existence of an independent database), try connecting to it in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: how can I know above query returns?

Answer (score 5):

To cover the range of possibilities (server doesn't exist, database doesn't exist, no login, no permissions, server down, etc) - the simplest idea is simply to try to connect as normal, and perform something trivial - `SELECT GETDATE()` for example. If you get an exception, there is a problem!

There are times (especially when dealing with out-of-process systems) when `try/catch` is the most pragmatic option.

Comment: Whoever downvoted that - it is a cheap shot (unless there is something I've done stupid?). It is the same as the accepted answer, answered in the same time-frame. You have my pity.

Comment: We found it necessary to execute a command, not just open a connection, for purposes of our "network status" check (which is really a "can we save stuff to the database" check).

Comment: @peacedog hence the SELECT GETDATE()

Comment: I was "affirming" your answer with that comment FWIW (I voted too!).

Comment: I loved the SELECT GETDATE() Fast check with controllable result

Answer (score 4):

You could just try connecting to it.  If it throws an exception, then the connection string is bad in some way, either the database doesn't exist, the password is wrong, or something else.

```
DbConnection db = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
try
{
    db.Open();
}
catch ( SqlException e )
{
    // Cannot connect to database
}
```

Comment: To be fair, this could fail for many reasons, such as incorrect format, disabled user, incorrect password and so on.

Comment: We found this method unreliable, fwiw.  Unplugged workstation from network and the code still reported an open connection.  Suspect it's a quirk of connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Entity Framework or have it available to you, you can simply call [Database.Exists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696588(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
if (Database.Exists(connectionString))
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It works and fits the "elegant" request.  It's far more elegant than using exceptions as part of the logic flow.  I did add the caveat about Entity Framework, which is a Microsoft library designed for use with MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Just try a DBConnection.Open() wrapped in a try block catching DBException.

About as elegant a solution as you are going to find.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = @name)
   CREATE DATABASE @name;
GO
```

or

```
IF db_id(@name) IS NOT NULL
   CREATE DATABASE @name;
GO
```

or [SqlConnection.ChangeDatabase(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.changedatabase.aspx). I think it could use less sql server resources then new connection attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me to verify the existence of any Postgres database with C#:

```
private bool chkDBExists(string connectionStr, string dbname)
{
    using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand
            ($"SELECT DATNAME FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE DATNAME = '{dbname}'", conn))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                var i = command.ExecuteScalar();
                conn.Close();
                if (i.ToString().Equals(dbname)) //always 'true' (if it exists) or 'null' (if it doesn't)
                    return true;
                else return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

** The if used in the try-catch statement could simply check if the return of the ExecuteScalar is null for non-existent DB and not-null if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can get list of Database with below and check your db name:

```
USE master
GO  
SELECT name, database_id, create_date  
FROM sys.databases ;  
GO
```