# Check sqlce database existence as per web.config

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Refer to the question [How to check for the existence of a DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873254/how-to-check-for-the-existence-of-a-db) I was trying to detect the existence of a DB as per in web.config connection string, but out of luck.

I was using the last answer of the above as my trial.

Trial 1:
*connection string in the web.config*

```
    <add name="sqlCEConnString" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf;Initial Catalog=master" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCE.4.0"/>
```

I got the error: **Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.**

Trial 2: without the keyword

string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlCEConnString"].ConnectionString;

```
    using(SqlCeConnection cnn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
    { 
        cnn.Open();
        using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("select count(*) from sys.databases where name = 'db.sdf'" , cnn))
        {
            int j=com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Result:" + j);
        }
    }
```

This time I got the following error:
**The specified table does not exist. [ @@sys.databases ]**

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the source code here, it detects if a SQL CE database file is present in an ASP.NET app, and creates it with tables if required: http://sqlcemembership.codeplex.com

Comment: thank you so much for the link. In the mean time I have tested using "Verify" method and it worked. I will try your link and let you know.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found the way to detect whether the DB exists as per connection string. Under the "SqlCeEngine" class there is a method named "Verify" by which it is possible to detect.

```
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlCEConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlCeEngine objCeEngine = new SqlCeEngine(conString))
    {
        if (!objCeEngine.Verify())
        {
            objCeEngine.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need to specify the connections where sqlce database is located.

try this link.

[Connectionstring.com / Sql Compact](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005-ce)

Regards!

Comment: In the connection string it has been told.

Comment: have you try.Data Source=//MyFilepath//MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;

Comment: do you think the following Data Source is not valid : connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|db.sdf;

Comment: It is also valid..but try to test another constring given on connectionstring.com ... and test it.