# How can I check the existence of database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for the existence of a DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873254/how-to-check-for-the-existence-of-a-db)

How can I check the existance of database and if it exist how can I delete it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873254/how-to-check-for-the-existence-of-a-db

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of [Check if Database Exists Before Creating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232227/check-if-database-exists-before-creating) you should be able to get your answer there.

Comment: drop database. select * from "figure out table of databases in sqlserver here". you meen database, right? and not database server...

Comment: In the dupe link noted above, note that the correct answer is not the best answer.  The best answer is the answer that does use master;select count(*) from sys.databases where name=@name

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page:

http://akrabat.com/winphp-challenge/retriving-a-list-of-database-from-sql-server/

It tells you how to retrieve a list of databases on an sql-server. After that, I think a

```
DROP DATABASE ...
```

should do the trick.